# Jquery - adding element above form to another div on button click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove the div (.item_desc) above the form to a sidebar when the button.additem is clicked. All of the processing of the form will be php/ajax, i just need a visual representation of whats going in the cart as the page wont be refreshing.

Form and divs

```
    <div class="item">      
        <div class="item_desc">
            Item 1<br>
            Item 1 Desc
        </div>
        <form method="post">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="additem">Add To Cart</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="desc" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="img" value="">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.additem').click(function(e) {
        $(this).closest('.item_desc').appendTo('#sidebar')
    });

});
</script>
```

Can't quite work out what i am doing wrong, have tried using the parent() selector and a few other things. Any help or a better way of doing it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest` selects the closest matching parent of the element. The target element is a sibling of the parent `form` element:

```
$(this).closest('form') // get the closest parent form element 
       .siblings('.item_desc') // get the sibling of the form element
       .appendTo('#sidebar');
```

You have also several other options like:

```
$(this).closest('.item') // get the closest `.item` parent/ancestor
       .children('.item_desc') // get the `.item_desc` children  
       .appendTo('#sidebar');
```

Also note that you should prevent the submission of the form either using `.preventDefault()` method of the `event` object or by returning a falsy value(`return false`) in the handler.

Comment: Thank you, works as i wanted. I appreciate the two answers, i wasn't quite grasping the parent/child relationship, now it's nice and clear. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

I added return false as clicking submit will reload the page (causing the element to go back to where it was). If you need the form to submit you will need to do an Ajax call

I also changed the code a little bit

```
  $('.additem').click(function(e) {
    var $itemDesc = $('.item_desc');
    $('#sidebar').append($itemDesc);
    return false;
  });
```

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bifq72JXtDLO5B4qPYpN?p=preview

You can see that when you click the button the background changes to red. This is because the #sidebar div has an inline background style of red to show its been moved